# how to write where condition in fql facebook using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, execute, facebook-fql

I need to execute a fql using facebook dll in asp.net. 
The fql is ="select name, profile_url from user where name = 'suresh'". When I execute this i could not get the response . I am getting only empty string.

string response = fbService.fql.query("select name, profile_url from user where name = 'suresh'");

but if i search by id i can get response..

so, how to search by name in that..

thanks
r.eswaran.

Answer (score 1):

The name field contains the full name.  It can't be a just a partial value.  Are you sure that the full value isn't something like 'Suresh Lastname' ?

I recommend you use the Facebook API Test Console to test out the queries. It can be found at:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools.php

Select "fql.query" as the method.  It will come up with a field where you can enter your FQL queries to test.

Comment: Hi, 
I have changed fql & tested in tool. It gives response but, when I try to use that in my web application (asp.net) i could not get reply I am getting empty string

Here is my code

using facebook.Components;
FacebookService fb = new FacebookService();
fb.ApplicationKey = "bfeefa69afdfe81975f0d6136ace3009";
fb.Secret = "9b672d682e1d8befd06382953fc2615b";
fb.IsDesktopApplication = false;

//here i am getting empty string
string s = fb.fql.query("select name, first_name from user where name = 'Suresh Rajan'");

Response.Write(s);  

how to resolve it?

thanks
r.e

Comment: Theres obviously something wrong with the FQL statement.  Do the single quote characters  need escaping? E.g: fb.fql.query("select name, first_name from user where name = ''Suresh Rajan''");